# how to script databricks jobs with completion

Tags: databricks

I'm trying to run a job on Databricks, making slight changes every time, and timing how long each takes.

When I start a job via the command line on a remove server e.g. `databricks jobs run-now --job-id ...`, is there a way I could time the output? Is there a way I could know when the job completes?

I want to run it in Perl with something like (pseudocode):

```
use Time::HiRes;
foreach my $entry (@entries) {
   my $time1 = Time::HiRes::time();
   system("databricks run-now --job-id ...")
   my $time2 = Time::HiRes::time();
   my $run_time = $time2-$time1;
}
```

but the problem is that the `databricks` command only submits the jobs, it doesn't give a return, at least as far as I know.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`databricks runs list --job-id <job_id>`

Will return a table listing information about all the runs for a specific job.

Then for each run:

`databricks runs get --run-id <run_id>`

Will return a json with various metadata about the job run.

The total duration of the run is the sum of the `setup_duration`, the `execution_duration`, and the `cleanup_duration`. Times are given in milliseconds, to read more see:

`https://docs.databricks.com/api/latest/jobs.html`